# One variable in the class displays but another doesn't

Tags: c++, class

Edit: full code: [ideone.com/e.js/7j2zkn](http://ideone.com/e.js/7j2zkn)

I've got a Customer class:

```
class Customer {
    public:
        Customer();
        Customer(string n);
        Customer(string n, string add, string acct);
        string display_short()const; // display customer info in format:
                                     // Customer name: Alice
                                     // Address: 2 North Street
        string display_all()const;   // display customer info in format:
                                     // Alice, 2 North Street, 234-567
        bool operator<(Customer right)const;  // compares Customer data member name
        string get_name()const;
    private:
        string name; // Multiple word name
        string address;
        string account_number;
};
```

and am implementing the display_short() function, it displays the name (minus the first initial) perfectly, however it won't display the address and I'm not sure why. I've double checked the spelling and can see no issues.

```
string Customer::display_short()const 
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    string shortName = name.substr(name.find(' ') + 1);
    cout << "Customer name: " << shortName << endl;
    cout << "Address: " << address << endl;
    return shortName;
}
```

This function is called to by another function which is part of another class.

```
string Job::display() const
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    cout << endl << job_details << endl;
    string name = customer.display_short();
    cout << "Case handled by: ";
    string handler;
    getline(cin, handler);
    return handler;
}
```

The customer class is initialised both with a hard coded one and also one entered by the user and have the same result with both types.

Here's the main code where it's got hard coded address:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Loading customers... \n\n\n\n" ;
    customerList.insert(Customer("D David", "1 West Street", "123-456"));
    customerList.insert(Customer("A Alice", "2 North Street", "234-567"));
    customerList.insert(Customer("C Carl", "3 East Street", "345-678"));
    customerList.insert(Customer("Z Zoro", "4 South Street", "456-789"));
    int selection;
    cout << "Number of jobs for today: ";
    cin >> selection;
    CreateJobs(selection);

    listJobs();
}
```

and the function where the user can input new customers

```
// Create a record for new customer if required
void newCustomer(string cust)
{
    string add;
    cout << "Customer address: ";
    getline(cin, add);

    string acct;
    cout << "Account number: ";
    getline(cin, acct);

    customerList.insert(Customer(cust, add, acct));
}
```

and finally my code to create the new customer:

```
Customer::Customer(string n, string add, string acct)
{
    name= n;
    address = add;
    account_number = acct;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Almost certainly it doesn't display the address because the address variable hasn't been assigned correctly. But that happens somewhere in the rest of your code, so it's hard to help. Post more code, preferably a complete program with irrelevant code removed.

Comment: Added more code to hopefully help

Comment: @Sarah Still can't see anything wrong, if I took that code you've posted and wrote the missing code myself I expect that I'd be able to see the address (I haven't done this though). It's why it's best to post complete programs. Please remove irrelevant code (which will be most of the code you've written) and post a minimal but complete program that still illustrates the problem. It's quite a bit of work for you to do this, but you will get an answer very quickly.

Comment: 1. Add error checking to your input calls! Always... 2. If not solved, if address is read correctly, add debug prints (or breakpoints if you can use a debugger) to see length of address at various places to see when it has contents and when it becomes empty.

Comment: I honestly don't know how I can cull it, each function leads to another. I added in a cout for the address upon creation and it displayed correctly. Here's the code: https://ideone.com/e.js/7j2zkn

Comment: Could it have to do with the creation of my customers and not having a class name then trying to call the class member functions using customer name.display().  I'm not sure why it's still calling the name correctly if that's the case then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that the issue was in my map, I was just adding the customer name string with the handler and not the customer object (which has the address). 
I needed to iterate through the set and get the value of the position using a pointer and send that to my map of job tasks (which calls on the display_short)

Answer (score 0):

Make `Customer(string n);` constructor explicit and use more meaningful names for your variables. In your code, you have variable `cust` which a string that contains the customer name and not a customer and you add a customer based on that name using the implicit conversion constructor in `CreateJobs` function.

By the way, your code is missing `const &` at a few places to avoid useless copy. One example is

```
bool operator<(Customer right)const;
```

It should be

```
bool operator<(const Customer &right) const;
```

instead. And better yet, it should be a free function for symmetry.

So start by making single argument constructor explicit and check if the code still compile. If not, make the call explicit if this is really what you want and otherwise fix the program and it might fix your problem.

If not, then use a debugger and trace the program to see when you loose your address.

If you really want to understand what is happening, it might help to add trace in each constructor and explicitly define copy (and move) constructor and also assignment operators for that purpose. Then adding trace in the destructor and maybe also adding an object id might help.

```
class Customer
{
    static int lastId;
    int id;

public:
     Customer() : id(++lastId) { cout << "Creating customer " << id << endl; }

     Customer(const Customer &rhs) 
         : name(rhs.name)
         , address(rhs.address)
         , account_nummber(rhs.account_number)
         , id(++lastId)
     {
         cout << "Copying customer " << rhs.id << " to new customer " << id << endl;
     }

     // Other code ommited...
};
```

Once your code is debugged, you can remove all that superfluous code. Be sure to make a copy of your code first once you have working code.